# Fixed Image On A Website

Tags: html, css

So I have a website [ZaxApps](http://new.zaxapps.com) that I coded. I have a fixed menu bar that stays with you as you scroll. But I also have a logo that I want to stay fixed at the top aswell as the bar. Anyone has any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Obviously...put the logo in the menu bar div. Simple!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to keep the image too as position fixed, the way you did for the bar, then do some position adjustments to position things correctly, refer the following code segment:

```
<center>
<img src="logo.png" style="
    position: fixed;
    top: 13px;
    left: 42%;
">
<br>
<br>
<label for="show-menu" class="show-menu">Menu</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="show-menu" role="button">
        <ul id="menu">
        <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">￬ Apps ￬</a>
            <ul class="hidden">
                <li><a href="hw.html">Day To Day HW</a></li>
                <li><a href="jokes.html">Day To Day Jokes</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
```

Hope you will avoid the inline styles by adding them to appropriate classes or create new one... :)

Answer (score 0):

try this in the CSS
you give your center from up a class

```
center{
 position: fixed;
 text-align: center;
 width: 100%;
 }
```

And then you give a margin top 150px to the h1